# twitter bootstrap 2.2.2 typeahead simple builtin function data source not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to work with bootstrap 2.2.2 typeahead which as per the documentation can be configured to some function for its Source option.

```
    $('#test').typeahead({           
        source: function (query, process) {
            return $.get('@Url.Action("Search")', { query: query }, function (data) {
                return process(data);
            });
        }
    });
```

this is what I'm trying.

my server side has simple action

```
    public ActionResult Search(string query)
    {
        var teamMembers = new List<String>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
        {
            var teammember = "john doe + ( " + i +" )";                                    
            teamMembers.Add(teammember);
        };

        return new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = teamMembers.ToArray(),
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
```

It can't get any simpler than this but my "Search" action doesn't get hit at all. If anybody can guide me what I'm doing wrong and how can TypeAhead invoke controller Action precisely by Source being set by some async. function using bootstrape 2.2.2 native component only. Do let me know if any clarification is required.

Static data working just fine so apparently there is no file that I'm missing here. as you can also see in the markup below.

```
    <input type="text" data-provide="typeahead"                                 
            data-source='["Deluxe Bicycle", "Super Deluxe Trampoline", "Super Duper Scooter"]'>
```

P.S pls don't mention any typeahead fork out there i'm only interested to know about twitter bootstrap 2.2.2 native typeAhead functionality.

**UPDATED: FULL CODE**
HomeController

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }        

    public ActionResult TypeAhead(string query)
    {
        var teamMembers = new List<String>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
        {
            var teammember = "john doe + ( " + i +" )";                                    
            teamMembers.Add(teammember);
        };

        return new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = teamMembers.ToArray(),
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }        
}
```

My current view markup.

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function() {

          $('#testSearch').typeahead({
              source: function (query, process) {
                  $.get('@Url.Action("TypeAhead")', { query: query }, function(data) {
                     process(data);
                  });
               }
          });        
      });

    </script>


    <ol class="round">               
      <li class="three">
        <input id="testSearch" data-provide="typeahead" >
     </li>        
   </ol>
```

Comment: Have you tried accessing the Search action directly? With your browser ? Try with static data to check if the typeahead is initialized at all.

Comment: @Sherbrow yes I can access my action controller "Search" action via my browser. static data is fine as well i've updated my question with the markup there.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong, you should check the process with the web inspector (ajax request, response headers, response content), and put some breakpoints in your JS to see what is executed. [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/c8tTv/2/)

Comment: @Sherbrow thanks for the fiddle but I still can't mark it as answer. Just wondering if somebody here used bootstrap Nuget package for typeahead may be there is some template issue.

Comment: I didn't give any real answer. If you resolve the problem, post the solution and accept it, if you still can't find anything, you could post the several steps that you tried for someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine for me.

I created a brand new project, got twitter bootstrap 2.2.2 from nuget and added the following code to the index view.

```
<input type="text" id="test" data-provide="typeahead"/>

<script>
$('#test').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        return $.get('@Url.Action("Search")', { query: query }, function (data) {
            return process(data);
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

I then copied and pasted your Search method into the home controller

After typing the letters J and O into the textbox, the typeahead functionality works as expected.

There must be something else that is causing problems for you.

Have you checked using web inspector or a tool like fiddler that requests are being made to the correct search endpoint when you type in the textbox?

Does it work for you if you create a new project?

Can you post the full code from your view here?

Comment: I've updated my question with full code. I can't see any activity in fiddler while I type in the input element. I'm testing this in newly created sample project because i couldn't get in my application.

Comment: I tried the exact same code that you posted and it works perfectly for me. What browser are you testing this in? Have you tried testing it in  a different browser?

Comment: I've tried, IE9, Chrome and FF. can you share sample solution with me somehow? that will be great. it might be pertaining to bundles config or something that i'm still trying to figure out

Comment: the code was right... the problem was with script bundles that were at the bottom of the layout page.